# Android NDK: Library doesn't build

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, subdirectory

I am a newbie to NDK Build system, although I know GNU Make quite well.

I am trying to define build system for my project with one Library and a test stub for testing the library.

I have the following setup, which sort of works but I am not happy with it.

```
--------------jni/Android.mk--------------
# A simple test for the minimal standard c library
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_LOCAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/library/Android.mk
---------------jni/Android.mk------------------

-------------jni/library/Android.mk----------------------
# A simple test for the minimal standard c library
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g -DDEBUG   
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc
LOCAL_MODULE := lteDiag
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.c)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g -DDEBUG  
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc
LOCAL_MODULE := DiagAppf
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../test_stub/test.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := lteDiag
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

----------------------jni/library/Android.mk-----------
```

This setup works if I run ndk-build under jni/library, but doesn't work from jni. From jni directory it does not build the library and simply removes the preexisting lib and creates a new empty archive.

I would actually want to do the following.

```
---------------------jni/Android.mk---------------
# A simple test for the minimal standard c library
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_LOCAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/DM_Library/Android.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g -DDEBUG  
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/DM_Library/inc
LOCAL_MODULE := DiagAppf
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test_stub/test.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := lteDiag
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

---------------jni/Android.mk---------------

-----------------jni/library/Android.mk-----------------
# A simple test for the minimal standard c library
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g -DDEBUG   
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc
LOCAL_MODULE := lteDiag
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.c)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

--------------------jni/library/Android.mk-----------
```

Thanks in advance for any help. Is there any documentation that I can go through. 
I am not finding anything that explains in detail building of a complex multiple subdirectory build system.

thanks,
Anand

Answer (score -1):

Kindly follow below steps, It may helps you.

1. First Create Android Project.Then Create "jni" folder inside project.
2. Put your c file inside the jni folder  and create a new file and name it as Android.mk
   type the Code.

   ```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE    := samplelib
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sample.c
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
   ```

   samplelib is the library created on libs folder after running project using this u should call inside activity.

sample.c is the c file that contains the JNI Export methods that is important to export to  Activity.

3.Paste follwoing codes into sample.c file,

```
    jint Java_com_example_ndkdemo_ADD (JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz,jint number1,jint number2)
    {
      int value = add(number1,number2);
      return value;
    }
```

In method "Java_com_example_ndkdemo_ADD" ,
  **Java** is Keyword 
  **com_example_ndkdemo** is the package name "com.example.ndkdemo"
  **ADD** is the MethodName 
  **jint** is int value

1. Goto rightclik on project ->properties->builder tab -> select New ->choose Program. window will open ->choose Location ->select Browse FileSystem -> Goto NdkFolder and Select ndk-build file  then in Working Directory Choose Browse workspace -> choose your project and select jni folder.

Comment: Sorry Gva. There are a few points that you have missed.
1) I want a Static Library
2) I already have a C library. 
3) I am able to get it to work with a single Android.mk file.
4) I want to set it up for multiple directories, with a hierarchy of mk files.
5) I have no use of Java in my project.